# Dreamhost rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, dreamhost

so I uploaded my rails app to my domain on dreamhost and pointed my web directory to public but when I try to load my website page this comes up

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/204/screenshot20110824at258.png/

I don't know what to do, this is my first time deploying a rails app

btw if you couldn't tell by the image I'm using passenger to deploy

Comment: Can you please add some relevant pieces of your error log here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following entry.. It skips all the complicated deployment process and will get you started pretty quick on DH .. [Fastest way to host ruby on rails on dreamhost](http://www.dahotre.com/programmings/host-ruby-on-rails-dreamhost/)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, early stage errors get logged in the system
error logfile which customers aren't allowed to see.

You need to contact Dreamhost customer support and ask them to check
the system error log file for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to access some error logs via CPanel, at least I can on HostMonster, which uses same system as DreamHost.

If you can't, then contacting the customter support is the only way. Setting up a virtual machine in VirtualBox with the same environment as DreamHost uses might help you debug something.